# MinGW Installation Manager - Missing devpropdef.h file

Tags: c++, mingw, openframeworks

I downloaded the MinGW Installation Manager and installed most of the packages available there in trying to find the 'devpropdef.h' file.

This file is needed by the openframeworks library and without it, I cannot compile the most basic project.

This file was listed by one of the contributors in this [thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/mingw-users/thread/CAPMxyhKDHWtjU6TnbM9RLYmWMsc55mxsEgAJ0b%3DagijzfT8F0w%40mail.gmail.com/), but I don't know what happened to it.

Does anyone know which package it is in from the MinGW installation manager? Or how I can get my hands on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://winlibs.com/ build of GCC/MinGW-w64 has a very recent version of MinGW-w64 which contains `devpropdef.h`.

Comment: Thanks. It did solve my issue with that file but still ended up with other missing ones. I ended up deleting it and using MSYS2 which included everything so far.